# Tag Synonym: [screen-capture] -> [recording]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[screen-capture](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) has 4 questions, [recording](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) has 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging and synonymizing have been completed.