# Of Screenshots and Recording: a plea to re-synonimise 'screen-capture'

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Currently, [screen-capture](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) is marked as a synonym of [recording](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) (See the related [meta-post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4960/tag-synonym-screen-capture-recording)), and meanwhile [screenshot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) exists by itself.

I think [screen-capture](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) should be the top-level tag, with the other two as synonyms. Why?

- Another name for a screenshot is *screencap* (short for capture)
- They both deal with taking copies of what is currently on screen (one video, the other photos)
- Screenshot is used for two different reasons currently:

  - As a [meta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22256/is-there-an-easy-way-to-view-my-steam-friends-screenshots)-[tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25119/need-for-speed-undercover-screenshots), and
  - As a how-to for different [games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-in-starcraft-2) and [platforms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9867/is-there-a-way-to-take-screenshots-from-a-ds) - generally leading to the answer "Use X software, Y Hardware, or Z method" (very similar to current [recording](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) questions.

Changing screenshot to be under screen-capture would help mitigate it's use as a meta-tag, and allow requests for handling any type of screen recording/capture to fall under the same roof.

The top-level [screen-capture](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) wiki excerpt could be something like:

> Questions should use this tag when asking about methods of taking pictures and video in certain games or platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the redirect from [screen-capture](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) to [recording](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording). It had a rename count of zero (although it probably doesn't mean much with the new tag editing interface) and didn't make sense.

As for [screenshot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) I'm not sure there's much that can be done via tag renamings. If the tag's being misused, we'll just have to remove it from offending questions. As for your tag wiki excerpt, consider submitting it as a suggested edit.

Comment: +1. The screen-capture synonym as it existed made no sense, but combining the two makes even less sense, IMO. Recording gameplay video is a specific domain of expertise that deserves its own tag.

Comment: Due to the ambiguity whether [tag:screen-capture] means [tag:recording] or [tag:screenshot], I propose either making both subtags synonyms of [tag:screen-capture] (the difference is marginal after all), _or_ blacklisting [tag:screen-capture] in order to force users to clearly state which of the two they mean

Comment: @Zommuter We can't blacklist tags. [tag:screen-capture] is no longer a tag that exists, though.

Comment: @Zommuter - Your first point is exactly my suggestion :P